# Rich text editor doesn't appear in Typo3

Tags: typo3, rich-text-editor, rte

I'm using TYPO3 CMS 6.2.3, and when I go to the Page tab, and try to edit some element, there's no RTE available above the text field. Do I have to install something extra?

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate "enable Rich Text Editor" under: USER TOOLS > User settings > Edit & Advanced functions > Checkbox "Enable Rich Text Editor (if available)"?

Greetings